# Generating number sequence as a string in macro

Tags: stata

Is there an easy way to generate a sequence in Stata like the **R** code:

```
seq(2000,2040, by=4)
```

I have tried the following:

```
set obs 11 
egen seq = fill(2000, 2004)
```

However, I do not want to generate a variable. Instead, I want to generate just a string so that I can put it into a local macro.

For example:

```
local x 2000 2004 2008 2012
```

Comment: Local macros and variables are different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `numlist` command:

```
. numlist "2000(4)2012"

. local x `r(numlist)'

. display "`x'"
2000 2004 2008 2012
```

See `help numlist` for full details.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question and your fast response! Still really new to programming, could I ask why directly writing local x numlist "2000(4)2012" will not work?

Comment: There is no way to run the command `numlist` while at the same time defining a local macro. You need to first run the command then save the returned item `r(numlist)` in a local macro `x`.